# ASP.NET Core API ISO8601 not parsed in local time when suffix is 'Z'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.2, timezone-offset

Scenario:
I have a REST-API that takes a POST-Request. As Body-Data there is passed a Datetime in ISO8601 Format.

```
{
    "validate": "2019-12-02T23:00:00Z",
    "configuration": {},
    "sortId": 1
}
```

With Modelbinding in MVC the Datetime gets parsed automaticly. The variable should be in the local timezone of the api-server. In this case Europe/Berlin. I would expect the time to be (refering to the example) to be on 2019-12-03:00:00:00. But this is not the case. It is still one hour off.

But when i post the following:

```
{
    "validate": "2019-12-02T23:00:00+00:00",
    "configuration": {},
    "sortId": 1
}
```

The parsing into the local timezone works as expected. Because the Client posting the data is written in JS and uses the default Date.toISOString() function, i always get a 'Z' in the ending. According to the ISO8601 this is totally fine.

Comment: `Z` means `UTC`. There's no problem to solve here.`The parsing into the local timezone works as expected.` no, it doesn't and shouldn't. Unless you got a DateTimeKind.UTC in the first place and a `DateTimeKind.Local` in the second case?

Comment: yes. it means UTC and the server should parse it into local time. Because +00:00 also means UTC.

When i have a iso timestamp, it has timezone information that should be evaluated in the program.

Comment: UTC is explicitly *NOT* local. `DateTime` has no support for offsets or timezones. It's [Kind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind?view=netframework-4.8) property can be Local, UTC or Undefined. `Z` explicitly means UTC. Other offsets should be translated to Undefined

Comment: BTW even the UK has DST rules, so what is `+00:00` in the winter can be `+01:00` in summer. Except for 1970, when it was summer time throughout, ie `+01:00`. That trips up people that try to naively caclulate Unix timestamps in the UK

Comment: If you really care about offsets, use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` and check the offset. DateTime provides methods like [ToLocalTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=netframework-4.8) or [SpecifyKind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.specifykind?view=netframework-4.8). This is a bit like codepages though. Unless you're sure about the source and target offset, you can end up with the wrong local time.

Comment: I work on flight reservation web services so I hate local times or assuming everything will be in some local offset - whose offset? Mine or the customer's? Countries often change DST rules, some of them with *very* little notice..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Z` explicitly means UTC. `+00:00` doesn't. The UK is at `00:00` now, but `01:00` in the summer. In 1970, summer time (`01:00`) was used for the entire year.

There are a couple of concepts involved here, and a bit of history. First of all, `DateTime` has no concept of offset or timezone. A `DateTime` can only be `UTC`, `Local` or `Undefined`, according to its [Kind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind?view=netframework-4.8) property.

Using `DateTime` means that the offset information is lost. The resulting value needs to be converted to *something*. To do that, the machine's offset is used. That is, the *web service machine's* offset, not the database server's.

And then, our container or application fails over to a machine with a default UTC timezone instead of our configured timezone. Over the weekend.

It's worth reading [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time), especially `8. The machine that a program runs on will always be in the GMT time zone.`

A better solution would be to use `DateTimeOffset`, although even that won't be able to handle DST rule changes.

An even better solution would be to use IANA timezone names and pass `Europe/Berlin` instead of offsets. That's not common usage though. Airlines at least post flight times both with offsets and timezone names.

**DateTime Parsing rules**

`DateTime` parsing rules convert `Z` or offsets to `Local` with conversion and anything else to `Unspecified` without conversion. This sounds strange but consider that `DateTime` was built to work on desktop applications, where `Local` time makes sense.

This code

```
var values=new[]{
"2019-12-02T23:00:00+00:00",
"2019-12-02T23:00:00Z",
"2019-12-02T23:00:00"
};
foreach(var value in values)
{
    var dt=DateTime.Parse(value);
    Console.WriteLine($"{dt:s}\t{dt.Kind}");
}
```

Produces :

```
2019-12-03T01:00:00  Local
2019-12-03T01:00:00  Local
2019-12-02T23:00:00  Unspecified
```

The `UTC` kind is lost here and, as a developer of flight reservation systems, I don't like that *at all*. Flight times are in the *airport's* local time, not my servers. Now I'll have to convert that value back to UTC or something, before saving it to a database. I have to convert it back to the original *airport* offset to print the tickets and send notifications.

And I'll have to reimburse you guys if there's any error, even if it's due to an airline's error.

**JSON.NET (really API) parsing rules**

JSON.NET on the other hand, parses strings with `Z` to UTC, Offsets to `Local` with conversion and no offset to `Undefined`. For an API that receives requests from anywhere, UTC is far more useful. Most hosters and cloud services provide UTC machines by default too.

This code :

```
class It
{
    public DateTime Dt{get;set;}
}


var values=new[]{
"{'dt':'2019-12-02T23:00:00+00:00'}",
"{'dt':'2019-12-02T23:00:00Z'}",
"{'dt':'2019-12-02T23:00:00'}"
};
foreach(var value in values)
{
    var dt=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<It>(value).Dt;
    Console.WriteLine($"{dt:s}\t{dt.Kind}");
}
```

Produces :

```
2019-12-03T01:00:00  Local
2019-12-02T23:00:00  Utc
2019-12-02T23:00:00  Unspecified
```

Better, but *I* don't like it. I still lose information.

**JSON with DateTimeOffset**

`DateTimeOffset` includes the offset so no information is lost. Unspecified offsets are treated as `Local` time. This snippet :

```
class It
{
    public DateTimeOffset Dt{get;set;}
}
void Main()
{
    var values=new[]{
    "{'dt':'2019-12-02T23:00:00+00:00'}",
    "{'dt':'2019-12-02T23:00:00Z'}",
    "{'dt':'2019-12-02T23:00:00'}"
    };
    foreach(var value in values)
    {
        var dt=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<It>(value).Dt;
        Console.WriteLine($"{dt:o}");
    }
    
}
```

Produces :

```
2019-12-02T23:00:00.0000000+00:00
2019-12-02T23:00:00.0000000+00:00
2019-12-02T23:00:00.0000000+02:00
```

**Why not UTC everywhere?**

Because that loses a lot of information that could easily make that time value unusable. There are a *lot* of SO questions where the poster tried to compare UTC time and got unexpected results because of DST effects or even DST changes.

A few years back Egypt changed its DST rules with a couple of weeks notice. Airlines and online agents weren't thrilled.

Besides, what if there are more than two timezones in play? International flights rarely land in the same timezone, so storing UTC doesn't work. *Airlines* don't publish schedules in UTC, they publish them as local time, with offset and IANA TZ names as additional info.

It's worth reading [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca), especially the parts that refer to UTC or GMT.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed explanation. Helped me a lot.

Comment: The best option is to always keep all date/times in UTC, no matter what. If you want to display in local time, do it at the time of displaying the value. If it's a windows application, you can use the computers timezone to convert the utc time to local. If it is a web page use the Moment Javascript library to handle the conversion from UTC to local time. But only use for display. Trough the entire system (backend/server/database) always use UTC.

Comment: @nivs1978 no it's not, not just due to DST changes. If you do, you lose information that's impossible to recover. There aren't just two offsets in the world, local and UTC. What if you have to deal with two different timezones? What if you have to store departure and arrival times for airports? There's a reason these aren't published in UTC. And then, tz rules can change at very short notice. Egypt changed its DST rules with only a couple of weeks notice a few years back

Comment: @nivs1978 btw I work for an online travel agency, so there's no "local" timezone, there are a *lot* of different timezones and rules that need to be taken into account. DST errors matter, not only because you'd be angry if the wrong trip duration was shown, the *price* changes too. And `00:00` (start of day) is not the same as `24:00` (end of day) either. Departures/arrivals in airports have specific timeslots per day, airlines have different price rules, so end-of-day matters. The actual offset matters

Comment: @nivs1978 in fact, even the offset loses the timezone information. +5 doesn't tell you *which* timezone this is, what rules are in effect or what the DST rules are. That's why everyone except Windows uses the IANA timezone database names. It's far better than storing UTC and having no idea at all what offsets are involved though

Comment: If you need to convert the UTC time to the time of a specific airport, you need to store that information in the airport. What time zone it is. Also if you hold users, and need to give them information, you store what timezone the user belongs to. Then the conversion from UTC to whatever time you need is easy. You can then tell people departure and arrival time in their local or the airports local time, as needed. And there is no such thing as 24:00:00 in a clock, the last second of the day is 23:59:59. I never heard of an airline on time or that used seconds for flight times anyway :-)

Comment: @nivs1978 I actually work for the 2nd largest online travel agent in Europe. You're wrong. Especially about how times are reported in search results. `And there is no such thing as 24:00:00 in a clock, the last second of the day is 23:59:59` oh yes it is. That's how airlines return flight results. We don't display the data this way to you though. As for the difference between `23:59:59` and `00:00:00` - that also affects your ticket price. The commissions charged by both airlines and OTAs depend on a lot of things, and date change is one of them.

Comment: @nivs1978 `If you need to convert the UTC time to the time of a specific airport, you need to store that information in the airport. What time zone it is.`. Arrivals and departures are reported in local *airport* time, not UTC, or the user's timezone. We don't convert them to UTC - that would be meaningless. Your search results and tickets are always in airport time. Never the end user's (customer's) time.

Comment: @nivs1978 `Then the conversion from UTC to whatever time you need is easy. ` no it's not. Because the posted time is now altered. If something goes wrong *I* would have to refund you. If the airline gets it wrong (and they do), they'd refund you, not me. As for keeping a list of timezones for the tens of thousands of airports out there, sure, it's doable BUT NOT USED for ticketing, only for display purposes, eg to mark a flight as a red-eye. *Precisely* because any error in that data is costly. And timezones change frequently. Russia changed 3 times in 2 years. Egypt gave <1 month notice

Comment: @nivs1978 so let's say we did what you suggest when either Russia or Egypt changed timezones. That means the UTC time has also changed. What do we do now? At the very least, we'd have to update all affected times with the new UTC, for up to 12 months, even though the actual departure and arrival times haven't changed.