# Does .net core web API convert DateTime to local time based on server location or request sender location?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Im passing UTC time from angular frontend / postman and web API is automatically converting it to local time.

Is it local time based on some header with timezone passed in request / request location or is it based on timezone of server that web API is deployed on?

@edit:

Is it because of setting default culture?

```
var requestLocalizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new 
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("pl"),
        SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
        SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
    };

app.UseRequestLocalization(requestLocalizationOptions);
```

Comment: No. ASP.NET Core doesn't do anything like that. It's something you're doing somewhere, somehow, but we have no code to look at to help you.

Comment: I set breakpoint just at opening { for endpoint and date is already changed. Its passed by Query params.

Comment: See this answer that addresses your questions - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59157801/968003.